# EPPlus not triggering existing formulas

Tags: epplus

I am trying to use EPPlus to use an existing Excel file to return a result. this excel file has a lot of formulas and calculations. so rewriting it with EPPlus is not feasible.  Is it possible to use EPPlus to trigger existing formulas in an Excel file?

I have tried using the calculate command as well as trying the different modes

```
workSheet.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to find searching online, is that the formula's have to be written in a certain way. I could not rewrite the entire file so we ended up going a different route all together